# Not all code routes produce a value, with a procedure I am sure it produces always something. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, size

I am working in C# with a procedure that has an array of structs M as an input and has to get a 2x2 table with some calculations. TablaContingencia's size is 2x2 (impossible to have a bigger size).

With *int[,] TablaContingencia = new int[2, 2];* I get "not all code routes obtain a value"
With  *int[,] TablaContingencia = new int[1, 1] {{0,0},{0,0}};* I get "Expected a matriz initialization with length 1".

Help!

```
        public static int[,] TablaContingencia(MAnalitica[] M)
    {
        int[,] TablaContingencia = new int[2, 2]; //Inicializes with size 2x2
        int categ = M.GetLength(0);
        for (int m = 0; m <= categ - 1; m = m + 1)
        {
            int k = M[m].P;
            int Pr0 = Convert.ToInt16(M[m].Conteo * (1 - M[m].PCliente));
            int Pr1 = Convert.ToInt16(M[m].Conteo * M[m].PCliente);
            TablaContingencia[k, 0] = TablaContingencia[k, 0] + Pr0;
            TablaContingencia[k, 1] = TablaContingencia[k, 1] + Pr1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:  =)

```
    public static int[,] TablaContingencia(MAnalitica[] M)
    {
      int[,] TablaContingencia = new int[2, 2]; //Inicializes with size 2x2
      int categ = M.GetLength(0);
      for (int m = 0; m <= categ - 1; m = m + 1)
      {
        int k = M[m].P;
        int Pr0 = Convert.ToInt16(M[m].Conteo * (1 - M[m].PCliente));
        int Pr1 = Convert.ToInt16(M[m].Conteo * M[m].PCliente);
        TablaContingencia[k, 0] = TablaContingencia[k, 0] + Pr0;
        TablaContingencia[k, 1] = TablaContingencia[k, 1] + Pr1;

       }
       return TablaContingencia;
   }
```

Comment: Nice! I had forgot the return statement. Thank you